# SQL Query that Selects All Rows with a Certain Date (The Most Recent Date, Prior to a Given Date)

Tags: sql

If the data is like this:

```
AsOfDate   |  Animal |  Version |  
2013/07/01 |  Cat    |    0.8   |  
2013/07/01 |  Dog    |    0.3   |  
2013/04/15 |  Cat    |    0.6   |  
2013/04/15 |  Dog    |    0.2   |  
2012/12/20 |  Cat    |    0.5   |  
2012/12/20 |  Dog    |    0.1   |
```

I want to be able to specify some given date parameter, for example, 2013/5/01 and have all the rows selected that have the ONE most recent date (2013/4/15) for a result:

```
2013/04/15 |  Cat    |    0.6   |
2013/04/15 |  Dog    |    0.2   |
```

Comment: How does 2013/5/01 fit into this equation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565360/mysql-get-nearest-records-to-specific-date-grouped-by-type Does this work ??

Comment: @Ek0nomik That is my example for the input parameter. I want to be able to see what versions existed for any given date. Each row of data can be thought of as a "status update". Versions are updated and include the time they were updated. So, the output shown above shows what versions existed at 2013/5/01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Select *
    from <TABLE NAME HERE>
    where AsOfDate = (Select Max(AsOfDate) 
                             from <TABLE NAME HERE>
                             where AsOfDate <= <INPUT DATE HERE>)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the OP wants the most recent date that isn't in the future so I'll suggest the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE AsOfDate = 
    (SELECT MAX(AsOfDate) 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE AsOfDate <= CURRENT_DATE())
```

Note that CURRENT_DATE is in the SQL92 standard (see [this IBM article](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rbhelp/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.redbrick.doc6.3/ciacg/ciacg25.htm)) and returns the date at execution.