# Get closest value lower than a specific value and group by

Tags: mysql

Is there a possibility to get the closest value lower than a specific value with a group function without a join?

```
date          productId    stock
2014-12-27    1            10
2014-12-31    1            20
2015-01-05    1            30
2014-12-28    2            10
2015-01-04    2            20
```

The value is for example the date and should be lower than 2015-01-01 but the highest date value and the result should be ordered by the stock sac, so the result should be:

```
date          productId    stock
2014-12-28    2            10
2014-12-31    1            20
```

Of course, this could be solves with a join, but a join is slower in large tables, isn't it?

Comment: No, that isn't correct since i'm interested in the stock value which could be anything.

Comment: sorry I assumed faster than I read. can you please post your sql, what you tried etc to clarify?

Comment: I've changed some dates to make it more sense. I could only imagine a solution with a `SELECT product_id, stock FROM table LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, stock FROM table WHERE date<'2015-01-01' LIMIT 0,1) as table2 ON table.product_id=table2.product_d`, but this a slow query on a large table.

Comment: how about `SELECT date, productId, stock FROM table GROUP BY date, productid, stock HAVING date < '2015-01-04' ORDER BY stock ASC` ?

Comment: If I should run this query, i get all the values lower than 2015-01-04, but I will only the highest value lower than the specific date.

Comment: So, you want the value belonging to the highest date before a given date, per product? I think this is the same problem as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565360/mysql-get-nearest-records-to-specific-date-grouped-by-type?rq=1), which I found in the 'Related questions' on the right.

Comment: That's correct, but it isn't a good solution in large tables in my opinion, isn't it?

Comment: It's OK, but generally uncorrelated queries perform faster than correlated ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the last day of 2014, it seems, for each distinct product id.

You do that with

```
             SELECT MAX(date) date, product_id   
               FROM yourtable
              WHERE date < '2015-01-01'
           GROUP BY product_id
```

That gives you a collection of `date, product_id`. A compound index on `(date, product_id)` will make this query very efficient to evaluate.

Then you `join` that to your main table, like so.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM yourtable AS a
  JOIN (
             SELECT MAX(date) date, product_id   
               FROM yourtable
              WHERE date < '2015-01-01'
           GROUP BY product_id
       ) AS b USING(date,product_id)
ORDER BY a.product_id, a.date
```

and that retrieves the detail records for the last item in 2014. The same compound index will accelerate the JOIN.

You're worried about JOIN performance, and that's legitimate. But it can be improved with proper indexing. There really isn't a better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for de detailed answer, I was indeed worried about the performance, but there isn't a better solution. One more question, the table have 5 columns, an AI, date column and 3 foreign keys. It depends on the query, but sometimes I will receive the combination of product_id and date and other times of color_id and date. Is it better to make two compound indexes (date,product_id & date,color_id) of just one single index on date since product_id and color_id are already indexes?

Comment: @Stefan, for satisfying this kind of query quickly the correct compound covering index is definitely needed. A single-column index on `color_id` won't help this sort of query. You should read about `GROUP BY` optimization to get the background. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: I understand that one, but is it really important to get an compound index on date and product_id of are two single indexes on date and product_id also correct?

Comment: @Stefan Two single column indexes do not substitute for a compound index in the efficient satisfying of `MAX()...GROUP BY` queries.

Comment: Thnx for your reaction!